# multiple MediaElement stop working wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mediaelement

```
private void Image_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    snare.Play();

}

private void tom3Img_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    tom3.Play();
}

private void tom2Img_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    tom2.Play();
}

private void tom1Img_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    tom1.Play();
}

private void kik_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    kick.Play();
}

private void lCrash_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    crashl.Play();
}

private void RCrash_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    crashr.Play();
}
```

in xml i have separate element for each sound

```
<MediaElement Name="snare" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" 
 Margin="385,566,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42" 
 Visibility="Collapsed" AutoPlay="False" Volume="150" Source="/Music/snare.wav"/>
```

these are my xml and cs codes im trying to create a drum kit in same way i did for windows store app. problem i can't understand some time some event works and stop if i make any changes to the other event.

All sound file in a folder call Music i try to create a media element in cs and set the source through cs code 
ex `snare.Source = new Uri("/Music/snare", UriKind.Relative);`
it doesn't work either. if some one can please help me to solve this problem.
audio files are really short

Comment: in xml
 <MediaElement Name="tom1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="385,566,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42" Visibility="Collapsed" AutoPlay="False" Volume="150" Source="/Music/tom1.wav"/>

Comment: Are you trying to play several sound in the same play with MediaElement?

Comment: If you feel this answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This will help future readers to find what they need (and trust it) and help to keep the focus on older questions which still don't have answers ;)

Answer (score 2):

If i have properly understood your need then your problem is that only one track/file can be played at a time with Windows Phone `MediaElement` (source [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202883%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)) :

> When a MediaElement control plays audio or video content, any
>   background sounds or media already playing are halted. The app
>   launches the playback experience when the user taps the control. Only
>   one MediaElement control can operate at a time.

To do such as thing, you probably have to use [XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207003%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Here is an interessing [link](http://mnjoe.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/windows-phone-8-playing-sounds/) that might help you and a few chosen quotes :

The author experience with Windows Store App/WP8 seems to be quite close from yours :

> First, I’ve written Windows 8 ‘Metro’ style apps which have played
>   sounds nicely, so when we started porting a Win8 app to WP8, AND
>   understanding that now WP8 is supposed to use the same kernel as Win8,
>   I thought porting the sounds would be a breeze.  Turns out there are
>   some subtle (and not-so-subtle) differences in the two platforms.

So he also had the same issue :

> Another ‘gotcha’
>   So far, we have only seen MediaElements used to play
>   sounds. However, on WP8, it turns out that one and ONLY one media
>   element can be playing at a time. SO – what to do if you need to have
>   multiple simultaneous sound effects playing together, as in a game?
>   Well, that’s where we can taps the XNA library and it’s SoundEffect.

And finally, he comes to this conclusion :

> Conclusion
>   So in the end, I settled on using the media element for
>   playing the background music in my app so I could start/stop
>   long-playing sound files at will, and using the SoundEffect from XNA
>   to play the sound effects, rapid-fire, with multiple sounds playing
>   all at once. Seems to work for me, best of luck to you!

Comment: Interesting that you have to fall back on XNA when it's not supported for new Windows Phone 8 apps. At least you can still reference some of the DLLs.

Comment: Thanks for all the info 
used some xna code 
       var soundfile = "Music/ESharp.wav"; //Note no slash before the Assets folder, and it's a WAV file!
            Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream(soundfile);
            SoundEffect effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
            FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
            effect.Play();
this works for me

Answer (score 0):

May be you just need to change the source of mediaElement on MouseLeftButtonDown event of your images.
Avoid using separate mediaElements for each sound. Just define a single MediaElement in xaml and change the source accordingly on every image event.

Something like this:

```
private void Image_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender,     System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  snare.Source= new Uri("snare.mp3, UriKind.Relative");
  snare.Play();

}
```